# How to copy values from a table into another table during PostgreSQL EF migration?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, migration, sequence, database-cursor

I use ASP.NET, PostgreSQL and Entity Framework.

I have to copy current values of the sequences I use into a new table.

Creating new table during migration is obvious. Then I can acquire all sequence names like follows:
`SELECT "sequence_name" FROM "information_schema"."sequences";`.
Then for each one I can find its current value like follows: `SELECT currval('<sequence_name>');`.

But I can't receive any data from `SELECT` during `Up` method of the EF migration.

What approach should I do? I mean how to retrieve data that I can then `INSERT`?

Just one strategy I can figure out is to add a procedure that would then be `EXEC` during this migration. But this seem to be not efficient since I need to call this query just once per history of the product.

Then the other question is how to compose `SELECT` from `"information_schema"."sequences"` with the `currval` for each row? I know about `CURSOR`. May someone suggest better way?

Comment: Good idea, create procedure via migration, execute this procedure, drop  procedure.